# Why do proxies not work when I use them with python requests

Tags: python

Ok so I was doing some things with proxies and python requests module.
When I sent a request to an IP logger it showed my real IP address instead of the proxy. I have tried several solutions to this and stack overflow is my last hope. No errors are thrown when I do this. Here is a sample of my code I hope someone here can help.

```
import requests

requests.get("https://exampleurl.com", proxies={"http": "http://123.123.123.123:8080"})
```

This code will not throw any errors when the url is a real url and the proxy is a real proxy, when  I send the request to a IP logger like this my IP is shown NOT the proxy IP.

Comment: You set an http proxy for an https URL.